# JPA / Hibernate unexpected AST node. Specify columns name dimanically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having this error:

```
10:54:38,330 ERROR SessionFactoryImpl:363 - Error in named query: transactions.auto org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: : near line 1, column 8 [select :fields from com.TransactionsEntity t where t.transactionDate >= :startDate and t.transactionDate <= :endDate order by id]
```

**unexpected AST node: :**

**select :fields from** com.TransactionsEntity t

Clean named query:

```
select :fields from com.TransactionsEntity t where t.transactionDate >= :startDate and t.transactionDate <= :endDate order by id
```

There are any way that I can add using parameteres the columns that I need select? I see that I can't use ":" in the select part of the statement.

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is a way. Please post your query here.

Comment: Also specify the field name you want to retrieve. And also tell whether you want multiple result or single result?

Comment: Multiple if there are, but I need specify the names from a previous loaded string like this: "t.field1, t.field2"...

Comment: Check my answer and try it

Comment: You cannot have a PARAMETER in the select clause, as per the JPQL BNF `select_expression ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable | OBJECT(identification_variable) | constructor_expression`

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select t.field1, t.field2 from com.TransactionsEntity t where t.transactionDate >= :startDate and t.transactionDate <= :endDate order by id");
```

It will return you the list of objects.

```
List<Object[]> returnedList = query.list();
```

You can iterate it as:

```
for (Object[] row: returnedList) {
    System.out.println("Field 1: " + row[0]);
    System.out.println("Field 2: " + row[1]);
}
```

Comment: Hi mehmood, I have this code working, only that I need create a replace string for the fields in namedquery, I cant make this:
"select t.field1, t.field2 from..." I need something like this "select :fields from", and then when I am working with Query object, make the replace. Just like date parameters

Comment: So you want to specify the column name dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, I want make dinamyc the columns

Comment: I think Criteria API of Hibernate might help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Check this might give a hint.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056199/hql-variable-column

Comment: fwiw he is using JPA, not Hibernate. There is no "session"

Comment: @NeilStockton that's just an example. The main concern is something else.